# Python Pandas Dataframe to Dictionary (Column Values to Keys/Values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe

```
+---+------------+-----------+
|   | wavelength | intensity |
+---+------------+-----------+
| 1 |        400 |        12 |
| 2 |        401 |        20 |
| 3 |        402 |        25 |
+---+------------+-----------+
```

and want to convert it to a dictionary

```
{400:12,
 401:20,
 402:25}
```

None of the [`orient`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) parameters for the `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict function` gives me this output. How do I best get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict(zip(df['wavelength'],df['intensity']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Series with index by `wavelength` column and then use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index('wavelength')['intensity'].to_dict()
```